# How to detect files that are not imported in a project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite

Recently I found that there are many "dead files" in my project which is complex.More than 100 files are not imported and useless after project iterations.

It is tedious and may cause some miss if use global find to descover the "dead files" in IDE.If there some convenient ways or thought to do this job with Node.js or Vite?

Comment: This may not strictly be on topic for Stack Overflow, but with programs like VS Code, you can use things like: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iulian-radu-at.find-unused-exports

Answer (score 0):

Probably to late, but for anybody viewing this thread, I use the [depcheck](https://github.com/depcheck/depcheck) plugin which is great to detect:

- any dependency that is imported in the code and not declared in package.json
- any dependency that is declared in package.json and not imported in the code (dead files)